# Syntax highlighting in source blocks in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I have an example of AWK code that I want to export to HTML, both the code and the result of the code. Since AWK codes are usually run in shell with `awk 'some awk code' file` I use the `shell` block. The `awk` block dosn't run the code, it throws a syntax error, presumably it's meant for pure AWK codes?! Not sure. In any case, the shell block colours everything inside quotes as a string in orangish colour. Is there a way to simply switch off the syntax highlighting? Or make the shell block use AWK highlighting? Or make AWK block run commands like `awk 'code' file`?

Comment: I found a way to disable the highlighting: `(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type nil)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AWK block with an input file like this:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC awk :in-file file.txt :exports results
  {print $4}
#+END_SRC
```

Don't forget to add awk to org-babel-do-load-languages

```el
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((awk . t)))
```

EDIT:

```sh
 awk -F ";" '{print $4}' test-awk.txt test-awk2.txt
```

same as

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC awk :in-file test-awk.txt test-awk2.txt :exports results
  BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $4}
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I need to show it as an example to be run in terminal as in `awk [options] 'code' file1 file2` etc.

Comment: Running an AWK is not the main issue, for pedagogical purposes I need the whole line of code in the export: `awk [options] 'code' files`. Your code only exports the code itself. But thanks for showing how to make AWK run in the code block, especially the `in-file` option.

Comment: For `awk`, you should be able to pass command-line options through the `cmd-line` header argument: `:cmd-line -F ";"`